# how to pause the newScheduledThreadPool?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm doing an application java and scene builder, I would create a `newScheduledThreadPool(1)`. When I click on the button, next when I click on the button again, executor must be pause and when I click button again executor resume his job.

This is my Code :

```
public  class  ExecutorThreadReadDatabase {
static Logger logger = MyLog4J.getInstance();
private static boolean stopThread ;
private static ExecutorThreadReadDatabase executorThreadReadDatabase;
private ScheduledExecutorService executor;
public ExecutorThreadReadDatabase() {
    executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
}
public  static ExecutorThreadReadDatabase getInstance() {
    if (executorThreadReadDatabase == null) {
        logger.info("null");    
        return new ExecutorThreadReadDatabase();
    } else {
        logger.info("not nullo");
        return executorThreadReadDatabase;
    }
    }

public  void readToDatabaseFromNetworkServer() {
    logger.info("lo stop è : "+stopThread);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(RunnableThread.getInstance(), 0, 5, 
TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
public void stopT() {
    logger.info("stoppo l' executor");
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.wait()
}
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What do you mean by "pause" the threadpool? Do you mean to skip scheduled executions?

Comment: yes,until i click button again

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way to do this would be to maintain a "paused" flag in `ExecutorThreadReadDatabase`, and wrap the `Runnable` you submit to the executor in another `Runnable`, checking the value of the paused flag before running:

```
public  class  ExecutorThreadReadDatabase {
  private volatile boolean paused = false;

  // ...

  public  void readToDatabaseFromNetworkServer() {
    logger.info("lo stop è : "+stopThread);

    RunnableThread rt = RunnableThread.getInstance();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        if (paused) return;
        rt.run();
      }
    };

    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: This does literally what you stated in the comment: that you want it to skip scheduled executions. (And your comment here doesn't make sense, I'm afraid. I know that English isn't your native language, but you'll have to clarify what you're trying to say).

Comment: yes, sorry,  :( I would that the executor not use memory until i press the button again..  executor interrupt schedule and resume again when a condition is verificated